# Adding columns from two files with numbered sum

Tags: file, awk, sum

I have a lot of files named like this: a.txt, b.txt read a.txt and b.txt result c.txt

a.txt

```
1 10
4 20
24 30
55 99
33 1245
```

b.txt

```
1 22
2 33
24 30
55 1
124 99
```

c.txt

```
1 32
2 33
4 20
24 60
33 1245 
55 100
124 99
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in your question which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: What are you looking for as output? What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2 } END{for(i in a){print i, a[i]}}' a.txt b.txt 
1 32
2 33
4 20
24 60
33 1245
55 100
124 99
```

Store the sums of any $2 in an arry, use $1 as the index per file,  at the end iterate over the array and print it.